# Symfony, redirect all request to spesific route inside listener

Tags: symfony-2.8

I'm usign symfony 2.8 and I'd like to redirect all requests to one route called **'coming-soon'** but it doesn't work for me. Is there another good solution better this ?

browser error

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

This is the listener:

```
    kernel.listener.redirect_listener:
    class: BaseBundle\Listener\RedirectListener
    arguments: [ '@router' ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

This is the listener:

```
namespace BaseBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class RedirectListener
{
    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = new Request();

        $routeName = $request->get('_route');

        if (!$event->isMasterRequest() and $routeName == 'coming-soon') {
            return;
        }

        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('coming-soon'));

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by getting the route name with **$event->getRequest()->get('_route');** not with **$request**

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{

    $routeName = $event->getRequest()->get('_route');

    if ($event->isMasterRequest() and $routeName == 'coming-soon') {
        return;
    }

    $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('coming-soon'));

    $event->setResponse($response);
}
```